# How to decompose $Z_{20} \times Z_{16} / \langle(10, 2)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to decompose the group $Z_{20} \times Z_{16} / \langle(10, 2)\rangle$ into a direct product of finite cyclic groups. Since the orders of $10$ and $2$ are $2$ and $8$ in $Z_{20}$ and $Z_{16}$, respectively, then the order of $(10,2)$ is $8$ and so $\langle(10, 2)\rangle$ has order $8$ and $[Z_{20} \times Z_{16}:\langle(10, 2)\rangle] = 40$.

For any coset $(k, l) + \langle(10, 2)\rangle$, we can choose the unique representative with $k \in \{0, ..., 9\}$, since $(k, l) + \langle(10, 2)\rangle = (k + 10, l + 2) + \langle(10, 2)\rangle$. If we fix $k$, then it seems like we can only choose $l = 0$ or $l = 1$, since $l = l + 2$. But then it seems like there are only $10 \cdot 2 = 20$ unique representatives, which is false by what I showed earlier. Could I get a hint as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is $(k, l) + \langle(10, 2)\rangle = (k + 10, l) + \langle(10, 2)\rangle$?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Sorry, fixed now. What I was trying to say is that if we want a unique representative of a coset, we can choose $k$ from $0,...,9$ and not bother with the other elements.

Comment: By calculating the Smith normal form of $\begin{bmatrix} 20 & 0 & 10 \\ 0 & 16 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ it looks like the group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z} / 20 \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Side note: I think "direct product" is a more accurate term in this context then "cross product".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=\left(Z_{20}{\;\oplus\,}Z_{16}\right)/ \langle(10, 2)\rangle$.

As you noted, $|G|=40$.

Let $x$ be the coset $(1,0)+\langle(10,2)\rangle$, and let $A=\langle{x}\rangle$.

Then $x$ has order $20$, hence $A$ is a cyclic group of order $20$.

Let $y$ be the coset $(5,1)+\langle(10,2)\rangle$, and let $B=\langle{y}\rangle$.

Then $y$ has order $2$, hence $B$ is a cyclic group of order $2$.

Note that $y\not\in A$, hence $A,B$ have trivial intersection.

Since the subgroup $A{\;\oplus\,}B$ of $G$ has $40$ elements, it must be all of $G$.

Hence $G\cong Z_{20}{\;\oplus\,}Z_{2}$.

Comment: $(10,1) + (10,1) = (0,2)$, which I don't think is an element of $\langle (10, 2) \rangle$; why is the order of $y$ equal to $2$? Also, why is it that we need $A$ and $B$ to intersect trivially? Thanks!

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium: Good catch! But now fixed, I think.Thanks (+1) for catching the error.

Comment: The fact that $A,B$ intersect trivially is what allows us to form an internal direct sum.

Comment: Ah okay, so it follows from $A \cap B$ being trivial that $AB$ and $A \times B$ are isomorphic; don't we also need to check that $A$ and $B$ are normal to determine that $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal.

Comment: I think the "recognition theorem" for the direct product just clicked for me, thanks for that :)

Comment: Would a choice of $(0, 2) + \langle (10, 2) \rangle$ not work for $y$? Since $(0,2) + (0,2) = (0,4)$ and so has order $2$.

Comment: The problem is that if $y=(0, 2) + \langle (10, 2) \rangle$, then
$$y\equiv (0,2)+(10,2)\equiv (10,4)\equiv (10,0)$$
hence $y\in A$.